Highcharts gradient color on vertical/horizontal line
I use Highcharts to draw Lollipops chart and It works well.
The issue I have is when I try to use gradient colors on a multicolor chart.
Version of multicolor lollipop with non gradient effect : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/hqnj91bv/
Version of multicolor lollipop with gradient effect : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/degpqus6/
The vertical bars (connectors) for lollipops are not visible.
I know that it is due to a non compatibility between gradient and vertical lines.
I tried to color connector with the non gradient version of each lollipop color but I cannot achieve that. The only way I can do is to fix the color of the connector with one non gradient color, but it is the same color for each connectors (it does not respect the multicolor aspect), with the property:
plotOptions: {
 series: {
  connectorColor: ug_palette[0]
 }
}

I also tried to change the path of each vertical connector by adding 0.001 to make the connector not 100% vertical but I didn't find the good way too...
Can you help me to find a solution on that please ?

Instead of assigning ug_palette[0] to the whole series through plotOptions you can assign certain elements from ug_palette array to individual points, like that: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8dkap05q/
